# R: Adding characters to a changing number of columns in list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

My script handles data from multiple sites (one df per site), organized in a list of dataframes. For subsequent analyses, I already added a match ID from all other sites (`matchID`, character) to each site (dataframe). Depending on the number of sites (=dataframes) in each project (=list, `data`), there are a varying amount of columns named "matchID" (no duplicate names). I need to alter these strings to add the site ID (`ID`) to the "matchID", so the result would be "ID_matchID". Normally, I would do this via 'paste()', but since the amount of columns to add the ID to can vary depending on the number of sites in the project and as a result the number of dataframes in the list, I need to add characters to multiple strings without explicitly using the column index (I think). I'd appreciate any help, especially tips as to how to handle those `NA` entries.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. WORKS - Extract all relevant columns containing matchIDs (since all dataframes are organized the exact same way (nr. of columns and positioning), I can just use [[1]]):

```
indx_match<-as.numeric(grep("match", colnames(data[[1]])))
```

2. DOES NOT WORK - Then adding the ID to all matchID columns doesn't work, cause the second x[,indx_match] blows up everything.

```
result<-lapply(data,function(x){x[,indx_match]<-paste(x$ID,x[,indx_match],sep="_");x})
```

Here is what the data could look like (in this example only 3 sites, hence two matchID columns:

```
> data
[[1]]
datetime            ID    matchID_50 matchID_51
2019-03-01 07:00:00 49         NA         NA
2019-03-01 07:10:00 49         NA         NA
2019-03-01 07:20:00 49    50_09_3    51_11_6
2019-03-01 07:30:00 49    50_12_6    51_05_6
2019-03-01 07:40:00 49    50_11_4    51_11_6
[[2]]
datetime            ID    matchID_49 matchID_51
2019-03-01 07:00:00 50    49_12_6    51_11_6
2019-03-01 07:10:00 50    49_21_6    51_32_0
2019-03-01 07:20:00 50    49_09_3    51_11_3
2019-03-01 07:30:00 50    49_12_6    51_05_6
2019-03-01 07:40:00 50    49_11_4    51_13_9
[[3]]
datetime            ID    matchID_49 matchID_50
2019-03-01 07:00:00 51         NA    50_14_1
2019-03-01 07:10:00 51    49_09_3         NA
2019-03-01 07:20:00 51    49_09_3    50_14_1
2019-03-01 07:30:00 51    49_12_5    50_01_7
2019-03-01 07:40:00 51    49_08_3    50_11_8
```

And this is what the result would ideally look like:

```
> result
[[1]]
datetime            ID    matchID_50    matchID_51
2019-03-01 07:00:00 49            NA            NA
2019-03-01 07:10:00 49            NA            NA
2019-03-01 07:20:00 49    49_50_09_3    49_51_11_6
2019-03-01 07:30:00 49    49_50_12_6    49_51_05_6
2019-03-01 07:40:00 49    49_50_11_4    49_51_11_6
[[2]]
datetime            ID    matchID_49    matchID_51
2019-03-01 07:00:00 50    50_49_12_6    50_51_11_6
2019-03-01 07:10:00 50    50_49_21_6    50_51_32_0
2019-03-01 07:20:00 50    50_49_09_3    50_51_11_3
2019-03-01 07:30:00 50    50_49_12_6    50_51_05_6
2019-03-01 07:40:00 50    50_49_11_4    50_51_13_9
[[3]]
datetime            ID    matchID_49    matchID_50
2019-03-01 07:00:00 51            NA    51_50_14_1
2019-03-01 07:10:00 51    51_49_09_3            NA
2019-03-01 07:20:00 51    51_49_09_3    51_50_14_1
2019-03-01 07:30:00 51    51_49_12_5    51_50_01_7
2019-03-01 07:40:00 51    51_49_08_3    51_50_11_8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for

```
library(dplyr)
result<-lapply(data,function(x){
  x %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("match")),function(z){ifelse(!is.na(z),paste0(.$ID,"_",z),z)})
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply. Well, yes and no. This way it adds the _ID to everything, including the NAs. Any chance we can preserve the NAs as NAs?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Edited. One way is to try capture it with ``ifelse``.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Yeah, my first question already done. :) On to the next one.